# A comparison in two sets of quantifiers and adjectives

Tags: differences, adjectives, comparisons, quantifiers, nuance

I learn almost every word on my own, in my productive if a bit peculiar way. I inevitably get perplexed by the ambiguity and the interchangeabilty between the words that I discover with more details.

I'd like to make my question into two parts with a view to solving it with efficiency.
Let work on the quantifiers first, I have come up with the following examples.

Set number one—shade, touch, suspicion, snatch, scrap, shadow.(they roughly mean a little amount of something both concrete or abstract).
The words are ordered by my consideration of their compatibility in the sentences. However, it would be even greater if you have some others in striking harmony with these sentences.

1. The tune conveys a shade/touch/suspicion (I preclude the possibility of the rest) of melancholy.
2. Her smile cannot mask a shade/shadow/touch of fear that actually keeps her trembling.
3. The executive struck me off without a touch/suspicion/sense (I suppose it would fit) of commiseration.
4. We just need a snatch/touch/scrap of sugar and we can start making a bundt cake.

Set number two—ephemeral, fleeting, instantaneous, evanescent. (From what I have learned, they are sometimes used to describe something that appears and disappears, and the whole process happens within a very short term of time).

1. At twilight, the flash of real beauty is evanescent/instantaneous/ephemeral.
2. These golden days that I spent with you were ephemeral/fleeting: they could never be retrieved.

Comment: But what is exactly your question? Do you want us to choose the right choice for each sentence?  And also offer alternatives? Notice that it may depend on your needs and the context (that you are not offering). I'm not flagging it but I think that your question is too broad. Maybe you should split it in various question, one per sentence, explaining the context and what are you exact doubts.

Comment: Also, you've got a repeated typo. It's quantifier instead of quntifier.

Comment: I'd use (1) nuance [[M-W sense 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nuance)] (or touch) / (2) undercurrent / (3) hint, trace or sign / (4) smidgen or tiny amount. But these fuzzy quantifiers take a long time and a lot of exposure to competent native speakers to master. If one ever does. // These are more POB, but I'd use (1) momentary / (2) ephemeral ('fleeting' has a greater connotation of  melancholy for me). // But one question at a time, please.

Comment: @RubioRic I have trouble using the right one (quantifiers), and the term 'quantifiers' has not been labeled, so I attaches 'adjectives' in hope of getting noticed. I will take your advice, and be more specific. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/ephemeral

Comment: They are not related words (do not share a hypernym) -- not synonyms (do not mean the same) but **incidentally** find use in similar contexts.